# Scrollbars not showing on ListView?

Tags: android

I have a standard ListView. It's not displaying the scrollbar track thumb though. Is there some special setting you need to set in order to show the scrollbars? My definition looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:dividerHeight="1dip" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The listview has data, and it has enough items to scroll.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try either including:

```
android:scrollbars="vertical"
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:scrollbars

or:

```
android:layout_height="wrap"
```